# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule: SKU option is not visible in Actions -> Conditions

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento V 1.9.0.1 and I tried to add the `Shopping Cart Price Rule` => `Buy X Get Y`.

I followed the steps in the magento [guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes#buy_x_get_y_when_x_is_not_1) but as I proceed I found out that the SKU option is not available when trying to add the condition.
The screen print is below.

[image]

I'm new to magento and I cannot understand why the option is not visible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, the `sku` attribute is not enabled for promo rule conditions. To use it for promo rules, go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`, click on the `sku` attribute, and set `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to `Yes`. Save it, and you should be able to use it for promo rules now.